# Save IPL_DEPTH_IMAGE for later processing

Tags: opencv, blob

Is there a way to store an image with IPL_DEPTH_IMAGE depth on the hdd for later processing? If I save it with cvSaveImage or the cvBlobs render function it gets converted to 8bit and therefore not all labeled are stored ;( 
Thanks,
Durin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [cvFileStorage](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=filestorage#CvFileStorage). It should be able to save the IPL_DEPTH_IMAGE for you.

Here is a short example from OpenCV docs:

```
#include "cxcore.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CvMat* mat = cvCreateMat( 3, 3, CV_32F );
    CvFileStorage* fs = cvOpenFileStorage( "example.yml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );

    cvSetIdentity( mat );
    cvWrite( fs, "A", mat, cvAttrList(0,0) );

    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fs );
    cvReleaseMat( &mat );
    return 0;
}
```

Hope you find that helpful!

Comment: Hi! Actually it fails ... it recognizes the IPL_DEPTH_IMAGE as float but it is declared as unsigned int. Therefore the output xml contains only NaN ;(

Comment: Hmm...can you edit your answer with the code you are trying to use?